# Detecting event.button of MouseEvent for non-standard buttons

Tags: firefox-addon

I allow users to record mouse combintations for my add-on. However I'm curious what happens when a 4th or 5th button is pressed? Will event.button be 3 and 4? I'm hoping it is.

```
function detect(e) {
    console.log('button pressed = ', e.button); //e.button is 0 for left, 1 for right, 2 for middle/wheel button
}

document.addEventListener('click', detect, false);
```

if `e.button` is not 3 or 4 is there a way to get it to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you could get this from [`MouseEvent.buttons`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent.buttons). In practice, however... Well, see the Gecko Notes section of the docs for yourself.

Comment: Oh wow `buttons` (with an `s`) is a new one on me. So I can just use bit wise testing. Like `if (buttons & 2)` it means right button was pressed. But I don't understand what you mean by "in theory" vs "in practice"? Docs take this up to a 5th button. Does it follow the same pattern, so like a 6th button would be flag of `sum of previous buttons + 1` so a 6th would be `32`? And 7th `64`? And 8th `128`? Also do u kno since what FF version do we support `buttons` the docs don't make that clear?

Comment: Read the docs page already, in particular the Gecko Notes section (scroll to the bottom) ;)

Comment: Oh crap I never read that section, just did. Wow basically it says, it doesnt work.... :( This sounded like a beutiful idea, I was all excieted and ready to keep the in memory the last `buttons` sum and then bit wise it out of the next one, to figure out what was the most recent button. And when all buttons released I would clear that thing from memory (so it doesnt mess up on next mouse button down) :'(

Comment: Btw that notes section is frikin HILARIOUS it says "the buttons feature works on Win, *nix, and Mac with the following exceptions: * Win: will work if btns not customized; *nix: wont work; Mac: wont work" wtf... HAHAHAHA